# Removing index reference of an array in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, arrays, object

So I know you can't physically remove an index from an array, but what I want to do is downsize it as objects in my array are no longer needed. I don't want the program to have to loop through endless unneeded objects as the array gets larger. Is splice the correct way to do this?

For reference I have an array of objects, that I need to loop through to check for certain conditions:

```
for(var i=0; i < arraywithobject.length, i++) {

   If (arraywithobject[i].key == true) { do things }

//iterating through array objects

arraywithobject[0]
arraywithobject[1]
arraywithobject[2]

}

// arraywithobject[2] is obsolete and reference is removed (splice?)

for(var i=0; i < arraywithobject.length, i++) {

   If (arraywithobject[i].key == true) { do things }

//iterating through array objects

arraywithobject[0]
arraywithobject[1]
arraywithobject[3]

}
```

I want to downsize the array so it doesnt iterate through the whole index array of objects as objects become obsolete. So say arraywithobject[2] becomes obsolete I want to remove any reference to it.  Setting it to null it would still iterate through it and seems a messy way to handle it, and the array itself would continue to get larger when I'd like to keep it efficient.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: If your list is large and you need frequent arbitrary removals, generally a Linked List is considered a better data structure for this than an array, as it affords you constant time removal.

Comment: Yes, `.splice()` is how you remove items from the middle of an array.  `.pop()` removes from the end, `.shift()` removes from the beginning.  `.splice()` can remove any number of elements from anywhere in the array.  Be very careful removing items from the array if you are in the middle of iterating the array as it can confuse the iteration when you move things around.

Comment: @JoshBothun - Copying memory is so ridiculously fast these days (optimized CPU 
 instructions) that I wouldn't add the extra complication of a linked list and all the extra heap objects unless the array was really big and there were lots of insertions and deletions.  IMO, this goes in the bucket of don't over-optimize until/unless you know you actually have a problem to solve.

Comment: This is where I got confused, because when I tried splice it looked like it was just trying to remove elements from that particular array and not the index reference itself. Like arraywithobject.splice(index,1) where index is a variable pointing to the index reference of the array seems to only be removing the first element of that particular array (like if index =0, it was only removing the first element from arraywithobject[0] )instead of the index reference itself.

Comment: When `.splice()` removes the `[0]` element from the array, it moves the other elements down in the array. So, if the length of the array was 7 and you remove the `[0]` item, then what was in the `[1]` element will now be in the `[0]` element and the length of the array will reduce by one down to a length of 6. That's what it means to remove an item from the array. If you just want to `null` an element in the array, then you can just do `array[0] = null`. The `[0]` item is still there, but you've reassigned its value to `null` and the other elements don't move. Pick which behavior you want.

Comment: Arrays are meant to be sequential. ordered collections with numeric keys.  They can be sparse, but are not very efficient that way and are not usually used that way.  You could also use an object, or a `Map` if you just want index access, but not sequential access where you can just directly remove an index from the `Map` or object.

Comment: Yeah I think a Map is probably the better option, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

> Since you need to delete the element if it is procesed, if you use a while loop and only increment the iterator if it hasnt been deleted from the array, that way you dont have to worry about the array changing size in the middle of the iterator.
> You can also filter the array and push the filtered contents into the array again after clearing it so you dont lose the reference to the array

```js
    const arrayWithObjects = [
      {index: 0, key: false}, 
      {index: 1, key: false}, 
      {index: 2, key: true},
      {index: 3, key: false},
      {index: 4, key: false},
      {index: 5, key: true},
      {index: 6, key: false},
      {index: 7, key: false}
     ];
    // indices 2 and 5 are true
    console.log(`Array before ${JSON.stringify(arrayWithObjects,null,4)}`);
    let it = 0;
    while(it < arrayWithObjects.length) {
      if(arrayWithObjects[it].key == true) {
        // do stuff and remove
        arrayWithObjects.splice(it,1)
      }else {
        it++;
      }
    }
    
    console.log(`Array after ${JSON.stringify(arrayWithObjects,null,4)}`);
```

```js
const arrayWithObjects = [
  {index: 0, key: false}, 
  {index: 1, key: false}, 
  {index: 2, key: true},
  {index: 3, key: false},
  {index: 4, key: false},
  {index: 5, key: true},
  {index: 6, key: false},
  {index: 7, key: false}
 ];
// indices 2 and 5 are true
console.log(`Array before ${JSON.stringify(arrayWithObjects,null,4)}`);
arrayWithObjects.forEach((obj) => {
  if(obj.key == true) {
    //do stuff
  }
})
arrayWithObjects.splice(0, arrayWithObjects.length, ...arrayWithObjects.filter((obj) => obj.key != true))

console.log(`Array after ${JSON.stringify(arrayWithObjects,null,4)}`);
// indices 2 and 5 are gone
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: you are right!, Thnx!